# Change wlan channel

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, wlan, access-point

I have 2 Wlan Routers with the same SSID. One on the channel 6 and one on the channel 11. By default I am connected to the one on the channel 6. How can I connect to the one on channel 11? (Of course I could just connect via LAN or power off the router with channel 6, but I'm searching for a solution where i connect to a specific endpoint)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The point is, from the normal point of client view, if is not easy to control automatic hoping/handing from AP to AP, and often you can get connected to the wrong/more distant AP when using the same SSID. Heck, the "secret sauce" of some enterprise solutions is actually dealing with those borderline cases. At home, I have two different SSIDs for 2.4 and 5GHz justly because of this problem. If you have them in different parts of the house an alternative solution is to keep them in the same channel/SSID and connect them via WDS, or via cable and play with their potency.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the cannel for you wireless interface using command `iwconfig interface channel N`

More info on MAN page: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/iwconfig.htm

Comment: Are you sure you can do that when the interface is in client mode? In that mode it must necessarily configure itself to whatever channel the AP it has decided to associate with is using.

Comment: in taht case one can use the MAC address of desired device `iwconfig interface ap xx:xx:xx:xx:x:xx`

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. -1 for incorrect answer.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm guessing the OP would like to know a way to select the desired AP by BSSID (MAC address) instead of ESSID (name) from the Linux mint GUI, where NetworkManager and all that "fun" stuff lives.

Comment: in that case OP shuld describe his question in more detail. both solutions are viable, aspecialy if AP gives chanell as auto, and not forcing it, then my answer is correct.

Comment: No, `iwconfig interface channel N` is not a viable/correct answer. It will not work for an interface in client mode.